# How to map sockaddr_in C Structure to Java using SWIG

Tags: java, swig

I have a C function that I want to call using Java via SWIG but I'm unsure how to handle the sockaddr_in C structure.  Anyone have any examples on how I can handle the sockaddr_in?

Comment: Do you want to make it compatible with the existing `java.net.InetAddress` class, or just wrap `sockaddr_in` with a usable interface?

Comment: I want to wrap it with a usable interface...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually an article on wrapping `sockaddr_in` on [swig.org](http://www.swig.org/papers/Py96/python96.html), although it looks slightly old now.

Basically what they did was write a function that creates a new `sockaddr_in` for you, taking arguments for the values that need to be filled in as things that are easy to pass around in Java. This is a slightly updated, trimmed version of the linked article:

```
%module sock          // Name of our module
%{
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

/* Set some values in the sockaddr_in structure */
struct sockaddr *new_sockaddr_in(short family, unsigned long hostid, int port) {
        struct sockaddr_in *addr;
        addr = (struct sockaddr_in *) malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        bzero((char *) addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        addr->sin_family = family;
        addr->sin_addr.s_addr = hostid;
        addr->sin_port = htons(port);
        return (struct sockaddr *) addr;
}
%}

// Add these constants
enum {AF_UNIX, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM, SOCK_RAW,
      IPPROTO_UDP, IPPROTO_TCP, INADDR_ANY};

#define  SIZEOF_SOCKADDR  sizeof(struct sockaddr)

// Wrap these functions
struct sockaddr *new_sockaddr_in(short family, unsigned long, int port);
```

---

There's a nicer way of wrapping this with SWIG though, we can write a typemap to use `java.net.InetSocketAddress` instead, which will feel far more "natural" on the Java side of the interface:

```
%typemap(jni) sockaddr_in *ADDR "jobject"
%typemap(jtype) sockaddr_in *ADDR "java.net.InetSocketAddress"
%typemap(jstype) sockaddr_in *ADDR "java.net.InetSocketAddress"

%typemap(in) (sockaddr_in *ADDR) {
  $1 = new sockaddr_in;
  $1->sin_family = AF_INET;
  jclass inetsockaddr = jenv->FindClass("java/net/InetSocketAddress");
  assert(inetsockaddr);
  // TODO: check return
  jmethodID pmid,addrmid,ipbytemid;
  pmid = jenv->GetMethodID(inetsockaddr, "getPort", "()I");
  assert(pmid);
  jint port = jenv->CallIntMethod($input, pmid);
  $1->sin_port = htons(port);
  jclass inetaddr = jenv->FindClass("java/net/InetAddress");
  assert(inetaddr);
  addrmid = jenv->GetMethodID(inetsockaddr, "getAddress", "()Ljava/net/InetAddress;");
  assert(addrmid);
  jobject addrobj = jenv->CallObjectMethod($input, addrmid);
  assert(addrobj);
  ipbytemid = jenv->GetMethodID(inetaddr, "getAddress", "()[B");
  assert(ipbytemid);
  jbyteArray barr = static_cast<jbyteArray>(jenv->CallObjectMethod(addrobj, ipbytemid));
  assert(barr);
  jbyte *bytes = jenv->GetByteArrayElements(barr, 0);
  assert(bytes);
  memcpy(&$1->sin_addr.s_addr, bytes, 4);
  $1->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl($1->sin_addr.s_addr);
  jenv->ReleaseByteArrayElements(barr, bytes, JNI_ABORT); // No changes copied back
}

%typemap(freearg) (sockaddr_in *ADDR) {
  delete $1;
}

%typemap(javain) sockaddr_in *ADDR "$javainput"
```

Basically this calls the `getAddress()` and `getPort()` methods of [`java.net.InetSocketAddress`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html) and uses the result to create a `struct sockaddr_in` for the call.

Notes:

1. I'm not 100% sure I've got the byte order right here
2. We ought to support AF_INET6 properly too - we'd need to inspect the given `InetSocketAddress` to see which sub-class it is in the typemap itself.
3. There's no `out` typemap. This is basically the reverse procedure, the JNI code will create new Java objects for us.
4. The asserts are pretty ugly.

---

For completeness there's also a third possible way of wrapping this, which involves no JNI, but writing a little bit of Java. What we do is have SWIG wrap the `struct sockaddr` as in the first example, but then have the wrapped functions that use `sockaddr` return a `java.net.InetSocketAddress` object still and supply some code for converting between the two. I'll give an example with an "out" typemap, i.e. for returning from functions.

Given:

```
sockaddr_in *make_stuff();
```

we can wrap it with:

```
%typemap(jstype) sockaddr_in *make_stuff "java.net.InetSocketAddress"
%typemap(javaout) sockaddr_in *make_stuff {
  long cPtr = $jnicall;
  sockaddr_in s = new sockaddr_in(cPtr, true);
  byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = (byte)s.getAddr(i);
  }
  java.net.InetAddress addr = null;
  try {
    addr = java.net.InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes);
  }
  catch (java.net.UnknownHostException e) {
    return null;
  }
  return new java.net.InetSocketAddress(addr, s.getPort());
}

%immutable;
struct sockaddr_in{
   %rename(family) sin_family;
   short sin_family;
   %extend {
     unsigned short getPort() const {
       return ntohs($self->sin_port);
     }
     char getAddr(int byte) const {
       const char *ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&$self->sin_addr.s_addr);
       return ptr[byte];
     }
   }
};
%mutable;

void do_stuff(sockaddr_in *ADDR);
```

We've specified how to wrap a `sockaddr_in` directly, but also instructed the return from the function itself to be the more appropriate Java type (`%typemap(jstype)`) and provided a small amount of Java to perform the conversion (`%typemap(javaout)`). We could do similar for an in typemap too. This doesn't handle `AF_INET6` addresses properly - I can't find an equivalent of `InetAddress.getByAddress()` for IPv6 addresses, so there should probably be an assert/exception for that case.

Comment: I'll try and do this a better way though.

Comment: @c12  I have an idea for a much better way that I'll try and find time to flesh out

Comment: thanks...I'm going to post another question with some more specifics about my situation that I didn't state originally that maybe you can address and get credit for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157401/change-swig-interface-file-to-allow-return-of-object-type-from-function

Comment: @c12 - I've added a proper typemap for this that makes functions take a normal `InetSocketAddress` as input now instead of a wrapped type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better answer, and I look forward to seeing it.  But this seems to work initially.

In your module.i:

```
%include "stdint.i"

%{
#include <arpa/inet.h>
%}

struct in_addr {
    uint32_t s_addr;
};

struct sockaddr_in {
    uint16_t sin_port;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;
};
```