# Segmentation Fault when converting IP address to text form

Tags: c, linux, berkeley-sockets

I am trying to convert the IP address of any client that connect to my server  to a text form as following:

```
    struct sockaddr_in *client_addr = NULL;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    char client_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    printf("Waiting for incomming connections!\n");
    if ((client.fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *) client_addr, &addrlen)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Accept() API failed.");
        continue;
    }

    // Convert Client address from binary to text.
    strcpy(client_ip, inet_ntoa(client_addr->sin_addr));
```

When I run the previous code, I get Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I also replaced the last line witt the following, but I got the same error:

```
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client_addr->sin_addr), client_ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

So What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have to allocate space for client_addr (with malloc)

There is some code on the answer here:
[How to map sockaddr_in C Structure to Java using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142028/how-to-map-sockaddr-in-c-structure-to-java-using-swig)

Answer (score 3):

You have not allocated memory for `client_addr`.
 It  could simply be

```
struct sockaddr_in client_addr
```

instead of

```
 struct sockaddr_in *client_addr = NULL;
```